# html of Ruby on rails draw rectangle with text inside

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, svg, html5-canvas

here is my objective, i have a bunch of data, a name array containing name value, and same for weight, height, color.

So in my controller function, i have the following
my database name Person

```
def display
  people= Person.all
end
```

And inside display.html.erb:

```
<h1> Display Result</h1>
<div id='chart'>
    <% @people.each do |x| %>
        <svg width="<%=x.weight%>" height="<%=x.height%>">
            <rect width = "<%=x.weight%>" height="<%=x.height%>" style="fill:<%=x.color%>;stroke-width:3;stroke:black">
            <text fill="#ffffff",50,50><%= x.name %></text>
        </svg>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

[image]
want to have something like above, as rectangle vary with height and weight, weight is horizontal and height is vertical.

Already able to draw the rectangle, but need to put the text inside the rectangle, any idea how can positioning it just inside the rectangle?
Any idea how can i fix it, thanks in advance for your kindly help!!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use rails concatenation to fix you height and width.

```
<h1> Display Result</h1>
<div id='chart'>
    <%= @people.each do |x| %>
    <svg width = "500" height = "500">
        <rect width="<%= x.weight %>" height="<%= x.height%>" style="fill:<%= x.color %>;stroke-width:3;stroke:black">
        <text fill="#ffffff">x.name</text>
    </svg>
    <% end %>
</div>
<%= link_to 'Back', {:controller => 'people', :action => 'index'}, id:'proceedss' %>
```